# UWP listview swipe delete issue

Tags: listview, uwp, swipe

I am working on a UWP project and tried to add a feature: swipe left and delete item from listview. I followed the instruction from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/swipe#how-does-swipe-work 
and download the sample code from https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/XamlUIBasics.
Basically, I update the SwipePage.xaml.cs file from the github and add more items in the listview items source. When there are more than 25 listview items, if one item is swiped and deleted, the listview randomly pick one listview item and cover it with the delete icon. After you click delete icon and delete that listview item, continue scroll up/down the listview will  crash the whole application.

Can anyone help solve this wired issue?

Comment: Please post your modified code also.

Answer (score 1):

The original code is flawed.

```
private void DeleteItem_ItemInvoked(SwipeItem sender, SwipeItemInvokedEventArgs args)
{
    int i = lv.Items.IndexOf(args.SwipeControl.DataContext);
    items.RemoveAt(1);
}
```

The items.RemoveAt should be removing ***i***, not ***1***

```
private void DeleteItem_ItemInvoked(SwipeItem sender, SwipeItemInvokedEventArgs args)
{
    int i = lv.Items.IndexOf(args.SwipeControl.DataContext);
    items.RemoveAt(i);
}
```